# What alternatives are there to Yii active form?

Tags: forms, activerecord, yii

I wish to build a form that does not create/update any active records. An example of such a form would be a search filter using check boxes for the user to select which categories to apply to the search.

Everything I read about forms in Yii is centred around the CActiveForm class. What is the Yii way to build forms that don't use active records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to embrace Yii's convenient form handling, you should use `CActiveForm`. It does not require `CActiveRecord`. But it always requires a model for your form data - which is a good thing, because this will keep the validation rules out of your view files. Instead of a `CActiveRecord` you could also build a simple model class from [`CFormModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel).

```
class SomeForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('name,email','required'),
            array('email','email'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Mi Michael, thanks for this, this makes sense to me. I've actually realised that the Yii demo's own contact form is implemented in this way. It has a model ContactForm (doesn't have a table assigned) that extends CFormModel. It's very similar to what you've shown above. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs of the [CHtml class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml).   While it contains all the active* method, there are plain form methods in there as well, such as [checkBox()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBox-detail) or [checkBoxList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail) that sound like what you're looking for.